# ERROR in The target entry-point "chart-directives" has missing dependencies: - ./../

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I want to integrating 'NativeScriptUIChartModule' In my package. But It couldn't complied the resources properly. It is gives warning and error.

```
WARNING in Entry point 'chart-directives' contains deep imports into '/Users/<username>/Desktop/projects/<app_path>/MobileApp/node_modules/@nativescript/angular/element-registry'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

ERROR in The target entry-point "chart-directives" has missing dependencies:
 - ./../
```

I could not understand what can i solved this problem. Please Help.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue with my nativescript angular 9 shared code, while running its web application which was working fine till yesterday . I am getting an error like this  :
ERROR in The target entry-point "@nativescript/angular" has missing dependencies:  - @nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem was for me at least, that I've installed the plugin using npm.

my solution is to delete the package installed from package-lock.json, and package.json
then install the plugin using 'tns plugin add' command.

or you should add ignore deep import matchers into ngcc.config.js file, according to
[ERROR in The target entry-point "@nativescript/angular" has missing dependencies on running a Nativescript Angular 9 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503501/error-in-the-target-entry-point-nativescript-angular-has-missing-dependencies)

Hope that my solution will help

cheers,
Jawdat

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Already have That Dependancy in my package.json